# how to set id for an google map marker to identify which one is selected?

Tags: android, google-maps

how to find which marker is selected in the list of markers in google map from onMarkerClicked(Marker marker) callback.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is to have a Hash with marker ID and your custom data. The Marker object might change if the activity is killed and restored but the ID will remain the same. You map would look like:

`HashMap<String, MyObject> markersAndObjects = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();`

Marker objects have a getId() method to get the ID.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Here i unable to set the id to the marker when i added the marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can get lat, long, marker id, etc of a selected marker from `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)` like :

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    Log.i("GoogleMapActivity", "onMarkerClick");
    LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
    String idSelected= marker.getId();
/*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Marker Clicked: " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();*/

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @KingsleyMitchell read question properly, question says : how to find which marker is selected in the list of markers.....

Comment: @KingsleyMitchell i tried to answer what he ask, you are trying to discuss on what he misspelled

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via `marker.setTag(MyMarkerTagObject)` and `marker.getTag(MyMarkerTagObject)`.

You'll just need to create a plain `MyMarkerTagObject` class that contains your `id` field (along with any other fields you would like to add) with setter/getter methods for those fields. For example:

```
MyMarkerTagObject myMarkerTagObject = new MyMarkerTagObject();
myMarkerTagObject.setId(someId);
marker.setTag(myMarkerTagObject);
```

And on the other side of things:

```
MyMarkerTagObject myMarkerTagObject = (MyMarkerTagObject)marker.getTag();
long sameId = myMarkerTagObject.getId();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can identify by id or title.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
      marker.getId()
      marker.getTitle();
});
```

Or you can extend Marker and in constructor pass every data which you want, and in onMarkerClick cast to your own Marker and get data.